# ng-table grouping doesn't work

Tags: grouping, ngtable

I would like using grouping for data in **ng-table**, But dosen't work and no **Error** in console.
I followed from http://ng-table.com/#/grouping/demo-grouping-basic and don't know data of **simpleList** !

```js
demoApp.controller('demoController', function($scope, NgTableParams) {

      $scope.testData = [{
        name: 'john',
        age: 50
      }, {
        name: 'albert',
        age: 25
      }];

      $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
        // initial grouping
        group: "name"
      }, {
        dataset: $scope.testData
      });
    }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <h3>ngTable directive</h3>
    <table ng-table="tableParamsPostCnt" class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover">
      <colgroup>
        <col width="30%" />
      </colgroup>

      <tr class="ng-table-group" ng-repeat-start="group in $groups">
        <td colspan="3">
          <a href="" ng-click="group.$hideRows = !group.$hideRows">
            <span class="glyphicon" ng-class="{ 'glyphicon-chevron-right': group.$hideRows, 'glyphicon-chevron-down': !group.$hideRows }"></span>
            <strong>{{ group.value }}</strong>
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr ng-hide="group.$hideRows" ng-repeat="user in group.data" ng-repeat-end>
        <td sortable="'name'" data-title="'name'" groupable="'name'" ng-if="false">
          {{user.name}}
        </td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<table ng-table="vm.tableParams" class="table" show-filter="true">

  <colgroup>
    <col width="60%" />
    <col width="20%" />
    <col width="20%" />
  </colgroup>
  <tr class="ng-table-group" ng-repeat-start="group in $groups">
    <td colspan="2">
      <a href="" ng-click="group.$hideRows = !group.$hideRows">
        <span class="glyphicon" ng-class="{ 'glyphicon-chevron-right': group.$hideRows, 'glyphicon-chevron-down': !group.$hideRows }"></span>
        <strong>{{ group.value }}</strong>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>

 <tr ng-hide="group.$hideRows" ng-repeat="user in group.data" ng-repeat-end>
    <td title="'Name'" filter="{ Name: 'text'}" sortable="'Name'">
      {{user.name}}
    </td>
    <td title="'Age'" filter="{ Value: 'number'}" sortable="'Value'">
      {{user.age}}
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: make sure the links that you using in the references are working.